# How to get the rect.top and rect.left of an element if it's mapped in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I am trying to have a gloss effect on some cards when the mouse moves over them.

What I need is to move the gloss effect base on the mouse position. The problem that I have is that I can't get the top and left of the card because they are mapped like this

```
          <div ref={cardsContainer} className={styles.cardsContainer}>
            {data.map((card, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                ref={cards}
                className={`${styles.card} cards`}
                onMouseMove={(index, e) => handleMouseMove(index, e)}
              >
                {card.title}
                <div
                  className={styles.cardGlow}
                  style={{ top: glowXPos, left: glowYPos }}
                ></div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

I have tried to use the index to get the rect of the element but it doesn't work. It's saying that `GlowingCardsGrid.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: index.getBoundingClientReact is not a function`.

```
  const handleMouseMove = (index, e) => {
    const rect = index.getBoundingClientReact();
    const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    setGlowXPos(x);
    setGlowYPos(y);
  };
```

Is there a way I could get the top and left of each element depending on which one I'm hovering on?

Comment: `e.target.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: it still doesn't work. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target'). I get the same error for e.clientX for some reason

Edited: Found the issue. I also had the index as an argument. I have removed it and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change some styles or classes when an element is hovered, the better approach would be to create a reusable component that could manage its own state.

Using `onMouseOver` to set a state variable to true and `onMouseOut` to set it back to false gives you the ability to do whatever you want (e.g., run an animation, add some styles or change the classes) when the element is hovered.

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((card, index) => (
                <HoverCard key={index}>
                    <h3>{card.title}</h3>
                </HoverCard>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

function HoverCard({ children }) {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = React.useState(false);
    const baseElementStyles = {
        backgroundColor: 'coral',
        color: 'white',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        display: 'grid',
        height: '10rem',
        margin: '1rem',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        placeContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
    };
    const hoverElementStyles = {
        backgroundColor: 'deeppink',
        position: 'absolute',
        inset: '0',
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)',
        transition: 'transform .2s ease-in-out',
    };
    return (
        <div
            onMouseOver={() => setIsHover(true)}
            onMouseOut={() => setIsHover(false)}
            style={baseElementStyles}
        >
            <div
                style={
                    !isHover
                        ? hoverElementStyles
                        : { ...hoverElementStyles, transform: 'translateX(0)' }
                }
            ></div>
            <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>{children}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

var data = [
    {
        title: 'Title 1',
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 2',
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 3',
    },
];


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```